# Image editor not working correctly

Tags: images

Here is my process..

- When editing a new post I click on the 'Set featured image' link
- I then select an image from the Media Library
- I click 'Edit Image'
- I make my changes in the edit image section (crop image and resize it)
- I click 'Save' to update the image

Now when I go back to the media library I can't see this edited version, only the original version before editing.  I get the same result even if I give the edited version a new name.

I am doing this on a fresh WordPress 3.8 install using the 2014 theme.

Can anyone help or am I going about things the wrong way?

Comment: You might want to turn debug on, and watch your javascript console, to see what's going on.  There may be an error that's taking place, but unless you set `WP_DEBUG` to true (in your wp-config.php file), you (likely) won't see the error.

Comment: I am already monitoring my error log and WordPress debug settings, nothing out of the ordinary.  This is happening with a fresh install as well on a different server.